# React Native - Efficient way to query redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Hello  I have redux state which holds all of my users profiles (synced with whats held in firebase).
When I want to find a particular userID in a list of 1000 users, I am looping though every user, using something like Object.entries(usersObject).forEach().

Is there a quicker way to find a key in a list of key/value pairs than to simply loop until you find a match?

Comment: the app should store only the profil about the current phone user, don't sync the profile about all users. image you have 1 0000 000 users

Comment: Without seeing your code, I may say, there're at least couple of improvements can be done: `Array.prototype.forEach()` actually iterates throughout the entire array (not ***until the match is found***), `Array.prototype.find()` does what you say; `Object.entries()` doesn't seem to be necessary here. So, for array of objects, where each record has `userId` key match is found with `arr.find(({userId}) => userId == id)`, where `id` is the value, you're looking for.

Comment: Feedback from @Yevgen provided a performance boost for my app

Comment: I would also recommend that you could transform the data slightly - instead of storing an array of objects, use the "userId" key to key the objects. Example: `const keyedData = usersData.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.userId]: curr }), {});`. This has some overhead of transforming the data, but the upside is O(1) lookup time later on (`const userToFind = state.users.data[userId];`)